# Adding my own appender through log4j configuration file

Tags: logging, log4j

I made my own appender :

```
class MyAppender : public AppenderSkeleton
{...
void MyAppender ::append(const spi::LoggingEventPtr& event, Pool& p)
{
    LogString log;
    log4cxx::helpers::Pool pool;
    printf("test\n");
    getLayout()->format(log, event, pool);
    ...
}
...
 boolean requiresLayout(){return false; }
...
}
```

Also I added it through log4j configuration file :

```
log4j.appender.MYAPPND=org.apache.log4j.MyAppender 
log4j.appender.MYAPPND.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.MYAPPND.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %d{%Z} [%-5p] [%t] [%c] [%C{1}.%M(%L)] - %m%n

log4j.logger.file.name = DEBUG, MYAPPND
```

It works nice till getLayout()->format(log, event, pool) {segmentation fault}.
Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited my question and answer is there now (all code needs always to be printed if it is possible). So, problem was into override method `requiresLayout`. It returns `false`, and `true` is right solution.

Comment: In Java getLayout() gives NullPointerException. You solved my problem thanks.